# Очередь проверок - перевод

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Слетел перевод в очереди проверок:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Астрологи объявили неделю переводов на SO, количество строк со слетевшим переводом увеличилось вдвое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В свежих строках ссылки на сайт и очередь сделали переменными. Обновил перевод с учетом этих изменений. Как обычно ждём дальнейших действий ответственных лиц.